# macOS weird logout issue

Tags: macos, bug

There is a weird logout issue on my MacBook Air (13", Early 2015), with macOS Sierra 10.12.4 installed. When I wake up my computer in the morning (it was neither turned off nor hibernated, but simply locked), I found that the system *wanted* to log out automatically. Since an application wasn't closed (that's Oracle VM VirtualBox, if it helps; an instance of VM was operating) the previous night, I saw a dialog asking whether I would continue to log out (probably in order to let me deal with the unsaved VM state). Also, I saw a file called "logout", 0KB in size, resided in the Downloads folder, which was created in the midnight.

Please help me figure out why this happens. It feels really strange. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Check Energy Saver**

It may be worth checking your energy saver preferences:

- Go to Apple menu > System Preferences
- Click on Energy Saver
- Click on the <kbd>Schedule</kbd> button at bottom right

Now check to see whether your Mac was scheduled to shutdown etc.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your MacBook Air into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your MacBook Air
2. Restart your MacBook Air
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Leave your MacBook Air in Safe Mode until the next morning
6. Wake your MacBook Air and see if the issue is still present
7. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal

Once you've booted into Safe Mode, let me know how you went and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thank you, but there isn't any scheduled shutdown.

Comment: It'd be good to know if this issue persists when you're booted into Safe Mode? I'll edit my answer with instructions.

Comment: Well the issue actually happened only once.